# Android URIMatcher problems

Tags: android, uri

I have this URI

```
content://com.mycompany.data/routes?group=M01&office=BOCE&zone=EC01
```

And this rule

```
sUriMatcher.addURI("com.mycompany.data", "routes" + "?group=*&office=*&zone=*", ROUTE_LIST);
```

Yet the select on sUriMatcher goes to the default case (Wired to throw an exception). Any ideas why the pattern won't match? (And yes, ROUTE_LIST is on the cases for the select, with it's respective break)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UriMatcher` ignores the query string (anything after the ? in the Uri). Your content provider must handle parameters between slashes if you want to use this class. For example :

```
sUriMatcher.addURI("com.mycompany.data", "group/*", ...);
sUriMatcher.addURI("com.mycompany.data", "office/*", ...);
sUriMatcher.addURI("com.mycompany.data", "group/*/office/*", ...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Wonder why this fact is not in the official documentation.

Comment: does that mean that I can't use the  (URIs containing queries) in my content provider AND it is impossible to match such type of uris in the UriMatcher???

Comment: So multiple query parameters are not supported in UriMatchers?